# Acronyms list size

Tags: lists, line-spacing, acronyms

```
\appendix
\chapter{Acronyms}
\singlespace
 \begin{acronym}
 \acro{BLAS}{Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms}
 \acro{CLR}{Common Language Runtime}
 \acro{DBMS}{Data Base Management System}
 \acro{DBMSs}{Data Base Management Systems}
 \acro{DDL}{Data Definition Language}
 \acro{VDL}{View Definition language}
  ...
\end{acronym}
```

I am getting:

[image]

How can I reduce the size of the list?
What would be the best approach to do so?
Should I change the `\singlespace`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've now looked at the documentation for `acronym`.  I'm going to assume that this is the package you're using.  Since `acronym` is essentially a list environment, you can reset the parameters for lists:

```
 \begin{acronym}
 \setlength{\parskip}{0ex}
 \setlength{\itemsep}{1ex}
 \acro{BLAS}{Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms}
 \acro{CLR}{Common Language Runtime}
 \acro{DBMS}{Data Base Management System}
 \acro{DBMSs}{Data Base Management Systems}
 \acro{DDL}{Data Definition Language}
 \acro{VDL}{View Definition language}
 \end{acronym}
```

[image]

**Alternatively** You can muck with the baselineskip value, as I originally suggested.  But this only has limited effect.  I don't do much building of appendices and such. But I would guess that you should be able to change the baselineskip by setting

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{<scale-factor>}%
\large\normalsize%
```

You have to say `\large\normalsize` since the baseline skip isn't changed until there's been a change in the font size.  At the end of the appendix, you can then write

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}%
\large\normalsize%
```

to restore things to the usual.

Just in case your document might use a different baseline stretch factor, you could try the following

```
\chapter{Appendix}
\let\oldbaselinestretch=\baselinestretch%
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{<scale-factor>}%
\large\normalsize%
\begin{acronym}
.
.
.
\end{acronym}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\oldbaselinestretch}%
\large\normalsize%
```

**NOTE**

I've kept the part about rescaling the baselineskip, because you may need to do a combination of the two approaches, particularly if you're using some other package (such as a thesis package) that sets the *usual* baseline stretch to some value other that `1`.

Comment: worked like a charm